# Неожиданный аргумент в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Использую классовый подход с наследованием и динамическим выбором методов.
Аргументы в методы передаю через `словари`.

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
method got an unexpected keyword argument keyword
```

Пример: `def test(a).` Я вызываю как: `test(a=1, b=2) b` - неожиданный аргумент.

Причина как-бы понятна.
Понимаю, что можно в методы вписать:

- `*` - Для сбора в кортежи.
- `**` - Для сбора в списки.

А игнорировать эти аргументы как-то можно, если нет смысла их собирать. Или лучше позаботится, чтобы в словаре при раскладывании "лишних" аргументов не было?

P.S Суть в том, что методы вызываются динамически, в зависимости от входных параметров, и аргументы прилетают тоже динамически. Мне, чтобы это убрать нужно хранить список всех аргументов методов где-то. Или использовать сбор таких параметров в методах. Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Лучше демонстрировать пример кода, где возникла ошибка.

Comment: Точно нет. Имя метода и аргумента я заменил. А вот с got - факт. https://i.imgur.com/LgU2OoW.png

Comment: Пример: `def test(a)`. Я вызываю как: `test(a=1, b=2)` b - неожиданный аргумент.

Comment: В таком случае неплохо бы освежить знания по созданию и использованию функций. Что по-вашему должны делать функция с b, если b в ней не предусмотрено?

Comment: Например, как в том же javascript - не использовать его.

Comment: если хотите как в том же яваскрипт, то и пишите на яваскрипт

Comment: Суть в том, что методы вызываются динамически, в зависимости от входных параметров, и аргументы прилетают тоже динамически. Мне, чтобы это убрать нужно хранить список всех аргументов методов где-то. Или использовать сбор таких параметров в методах. Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Если метод где-то вызывется, то там же написано что-то вроде ``a(a=1, b=2)``. Значит это ``b=2`` надо из вызова убрать.

Comment: Методы вызывается как: `def orchestrator(self, controller, controller_args)`. Где `controller` - метод, что будет вызван, а `controller_args` - его аргументы. Дальше, оркестратор резолвит метод через `getattr`, после чего ему передаются аргументы, как `**controller_args`. `controller_args` - словарь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` и `**` как операторы-префиксы используются для распаковки итерируемых объектов и словарей, соответственно. И для захвата аргументов переданных в функцию.

Касательно вашего примера

```
def test(a):
   pass

test(a=1, b=2)
```

Выдаст ошибку, так как функция ожидает только 1 аргумент, а вы передаете неизвестный именованный аргумент, о чем ошибка Вам и сообщает.

Если кол-во входящих параметров неизвестны, то используются выше указанные операторы.
как пример:

```
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    for i in args:
        print(i)
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print(f'{k}-{v}')
```

В такую функцию можно передавать сколь угодно параметров.

```
test(1,2,3, a=4, b=5)
# Out
1
2
3
a-4
b-5
```

Можно совмещать с ожидаемымси параметрами.

```
def test(arg1, *args, **kwargs):
    print(f'this is arg1 {arg1}')
    for i in args:
        print(i)
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print(f'{k}-{v}')
#out
this is arg1 1
2
3
a-4
b-5
```

Так же операторы можно использовать для распаковки аргументов. * - любой итерируемый объект. ** - словарь.

```
print(*(1, 2, 3)) # 1 2 3
print(*[1, 2, 3]) # 1 2 3
print(*{1, 2, 3}) # 1 2 3
print(*{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3}) # 1 2 3
```

Этим можно пользоваться при передачи параметров в функцию.

```
dict_args = {
    "arg1": 25,
    "arg2": 100
}


def test(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg2-arg1)

test(**dict_args) # 75
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def strict(a=1):
    print(a)


def flexible(**kwargs):
    a = kwargs.get('a')
    print(a)
    

args = dict(a=1, b=2)


strict(**args)  # Ошибка
flexible(**args)  # Нет ошибки, "b" просто проигнорируется
```

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант, каждому методу кроме нужных ему параметров добавить параметр с двумя звездочками `**`, тогда все "лишние" именованные параметры будут попадать в этот параметр:

```
def test(a, **_):
   pass


test(a=1, b=2)
args = dict(a=1, b=2)
test(**args)  # Так тоже будет работать
```